# Migrate from Table to Temporal Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Starting with this basic table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Wage]
(
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,          <- no PK yet
    [HourlyWage] [money] NOT NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wage] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Wage_User] 
        FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Wage_User]
GO
```

I populate multiple records with what will end up being a temporal table:

[image: rows]

Now I want to make this a temporal table but my `UserId` column has no PK:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wage] 
    ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)

-- SET SYSTEM_VERSIONING TO ON
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wage]
SET 
    (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[WageHistory] , DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON ))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wage] ALTER COLUMN ValidFrom ADD HIDDEN;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wage] ALTER COLUMN ValidTo ADD HIDDEN;
```

I get this error on the first line:

> ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME failed because table 'dbo.Wage' contains records where end of period is not equal to MAX datetime.

I think this is because I need to set the primary key back up, but I can't do it first as it obviously has duplicate data in this column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wage] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Wage PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserId)
```

Anybody know how I can make this table a temporal table and keep all this added history?

Some how I need to get the PK back in at the same time I am setting it up as a temporal I'm guessing. Maybe I am going about this all wrong... can I insert into a temporal table with custom `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` columns in the insert, I am under the impression I cannot.

Comment: Any chance of adding a script to your question with that test data? I think I have a reasonable solution but would like to try with what you've got and the thought of typing all that in from a screenshot doesn't spark joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do an in-place non-temporal => temporal migration in the way you've tried, because as you discovered the final temporal schema conflicts with the current schema. Instead you'll have to setup new tables to mimic the temporal structure that SQL Server uses, and copy data around:

- create new standard tables `Wage_history` and `Wage_temporal` with the same schema as the current `Wage` (including the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` columns)
- copy all historical (non-current) data from `Wage` to `Wage_history`
- copy all current data from `Wage` to `Wage_temporal`
- define the temporal period columns in `Wage_temporal`:

```
ALTER TABLE Wage_temporal ADD PERIOD
FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([ValidFrom], [ValidTo]);
```

- set `Wage_temporal` to be a temporal table with its history located in `Wage_history`:

```
ALTER TABLE Wage_temporal SET (
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (
        HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.Wage_history,
        DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON
    )
);
```

- rename `Wage` to `Wage_migrated`, and `Wage_temporal` to `Wage`

Comment: Ah thanks Ian! Once I realized that I need to move the older records (anything that doesn't end in 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999) into the new history table everything worked well after that!

Answer (score 0):

As an example to do such as Ian Kemp says, is taken from my website "[tables temporelles avec SQL Server](https://blog.developpez.com/sqlpro/p13141/langage-sql-norme/les-tables-temporelles-avec-sql-server-presentation)" (in french)

```
-- creating tables structure for the test :

CREATE SEQUENCE SQC_EMP AS INT START WITH 1;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP
(EMP_ID                      INT NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SQC_EMP,
 EMP_MATRICULE               CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
 EMP_NOM                     CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 EMP_PRENOM                  VARCHAR(25),
 EMP_DATE_NAISSANCE          DATE,
 EMP_DATE_EMBAUCHE           DATE NOT NULL,
 EMP_DATE_DEBAUCHE           DATE,
 EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL         DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL,
 EMP_HEURES                  FLOAT NOT NULL,
 EMP_STATUT                  CHAR(12) NOT NULL 
                             CHECK (EMP_STATUT 
                                       IN ('Manœuvre', 'OS', 'ETAM', 
                                           'Cadre', 'Cadre sup.', 'Dirigeant')),
 EMP_FONCTION                VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 EMP_SERVICE                 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,  
 EMP_DH_DEBUT                DATETIME2 NOT NULL, 
 EMP_DH_FIN                  DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999'
 --CONSTRAINT CK_EMP_DEB_FIN CHECK(EMP_DH_DEBUT < EMP_DH_FIN),
 --CONSTRAINT UK_EMP_MAT_DEB UNIQUE(EMP_MATRICULE, EMP_DH_DEBUT),
 --CONSTRAINT PK_EMP PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID, EMP_DH_DEBUT)
)
GO

-- inserting primary data

INSERT INTO dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP 
       (EMP_MATRICULE, EMP_NOM,    EMP_PRENOM, EMP_DATE_NAISSANCE, EMP_DATE_EMBAUCHE, EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL, EMP_HEURES, EMP_STATUT,  EMP_FONCTION, EMP_SERVICE,   EMP_DH_DEBUT)
VALUES ('A0001',       'DUPONT',   'Daniel',   '1955-03-12',       '1975-09-02',      400,                 40,         'Manœuvre', 'Cariste',    'STOCK',        '1975-09-01 11:22:33'),
       ('C0001',       'MARTIN',   'Marcel',   '1952-06-17',       '1977-01-02',      410,                 40,         'OS',       'Chauffeur',  'STOCK',        '1977-01-02 09:53:45'),
       ('E0001',       'ENVIN',    'Élise',    '1958-01-23',       '1979-03-01',      400,                 40,         'ETAM',     'Vendeur',    'VENTE',        '1979-03-10 10:22:44'),
       ('E0002',       'AMBLARD',  'Alain',    '1952-11-16',       '1979-09-10',      450,                 40,         'ETAM',     'Vendeur',    'VENTE',        '1979-09-02 10:11:12'),
       ('E0003',       'BONNARD',  'Basil',    '1956-12-01',       '1979-09-15',      500,                 40,         'ETAM',     'Comptable',  'COMPTABILITÉ', '1979-09-02 10:13:57'),
       ('F0001',       'CARDEAU',  'Claude',   '1960-04-21',       '1980-01-10',      850,                 40,         'Cadre',    'Ingénieur',  'CONCEPTION',   '1980-01-20 17:12:21'),
       ('F0002',       'DIDOT',    'Damien',   '1958-02-11',       '1980-04-01',      600,                 40,         'ETAM',     'Tourneur',   'PRODUCTION',   '1980-04-01 09:02:17'),
       ('F0003',       'FORTIER',  'Fabien',   '1959-09-02',       '1980-04-01',      600,                 40,         'ETAM',     'Fraiseur',   'PRODUCTION',   '1980-04-01 09:18:49'),
       ('F0004',       'GAVOT',    'Gérard',   '1961-09-02',       '1980-09-02',      450,                 40,         'ETAM',     'Vendeur',    'VENTE',        '1980-09-01 15:28:43'),
       ('J0001',       'HOUDOT',   'Henri',    '1952-11-29',       '1984-06-01',      1200,                39,         'Cadre',    'DAF',        'DIRECTION',    '1984-06-01 09:59:52');
GO

-- do some movement to simulate history

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- reforme 39 heures  => 1/3/1982

INSERT INTO dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP 
      (EMP_ID, EMP_MATRICULE, EMP_NOM,    EMP_PRENOM, EMP_DATE_NAISSANCE, EMP_DATE_EMBAUCHE, EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL, EMP_HEURES, EMP_STATUT,  EMP_FONCTION, EMP_SERVICE, EMP_DH_DEBUT, EMP_DH_FIN)
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_MATRICULE, EMP_NOM,    EMP_PRENOM, EMP_DATE_NAISSANCE, EMP_DATE_EMBAUCHE, EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL, EMP_HEURES, EMP_STATUT,  EMP_FONCTION, EMP_SERVICE, EMP_DH_DEBUT, '1982-03-01 09:10:37'
FROM   dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP AS E1
WHERE  EMP_DH_DEBUT = (SELECT MAX (EMP_DH_DEBUT) FROM dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP AS E2 WHERE E1.EMP_MATRICULE = E2.EMP_MATRICULE)
  AND  EMP_DH_DEBUT < '1982-03-01 09:10:37';

UPDATE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP 
SET    EMP_HEURES = 39, EMP_DH_DEBUT = '1982-03-01 09:10:37'
WHERE  EMP_DH_FIN = '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999' AND  EMP_DH_DEBUT < '1982-03-01 09:10:37';

-- réforme des 35 heures => 1/1/2002 (et 10% de salaire en moins !)

INSERT INTO dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP 
      (EMP_ID, EMP_MATRICULE, EMP_NOM,    EMP_PRENOM, EMP_DATE_NAISSANCE, EMP_DATE_EMBAUCHE, EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL, EMP_HEURES, EMP_STATUT,  EMP_FONCTION, EMP_SERVICE, EMP_DH_DEBUT, EMP_DH_FIN)
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_MATRICULE, EMP_NOM,    EMP_PRENOM, EMP_DATE_NAISSANCE, EMP_DATE_EMBAUCHE, EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL, EMP_HEURES, EMP_STATUT,  EMP_FONCTION, EMP_SERVICE, EMP_DH_DEBUT, '2002-01-02 11:22:33'
FROM   dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP AS E1
WHERE  EMP_DH_DEBUT = (SELECT MAX (EMP_DH_DEBUT) FROM dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP AS E2 WHERE E1.EMP_MATRICULE = E2.EMP_MATRICULE);

UPDATE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP 
SET    EMP_HEURES = 35, EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL = EMP_SALAIRE_MENSUEL * 0.9, EMP_DH_DEBUT = '2002-01-02 11:22:33'
WHERE  EMP_DH_FIN = '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999' -- AND EMP_DH_DEBUT = '1982-03-01 09:10:37';

SELECT * FROM dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP ORDER BY EMP_ID, EMP_DH_DEBUT;

COMMIT
GO

-- now we have an in situ actual and historical data in the same table...
-- processing the temporals action to split between actual table an temporal table

--> PHASE 1, migrate in two tables

--> move the history to a new tabled'historisation
SELECT * INTO dbo.T_EMPLOYE_HISTORIQUE_EMP FROM dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP WHERE EMP_DH_FIN <> '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999';

--> delete history from the actual table
DELETE FROM dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP WHERE EMP_DH_FIN <> '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999';
GO

-- add a PK for the actual table (if not exists)
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EMP PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID);
GO

-- add default values for periods
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP
    ADD DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME() FOR EMP_DH_DEBUT;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP
    ADD DEFAULT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999' AS DATETIME2) FOR EMP_DH_FIN;
GO

-- add temporal period
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP
   ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (EMP_DH_DEBUT, EMP_DH_FIN);
GO

-- add versionning
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP
   SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.T_EMPLOYE_HISTORIQUE_EMP, 
                                DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));
GO

--> if you want to rename columns
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP.EMP_DH_DEBUT', '_EMP_DH_DEBUT', 'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP.EMP_DH_FIN', '_EMP_DH_FIN', 'COLUMN';
--> !!! ceci à renommé les colonnes dans les deux tables !
GO

--> to set temporal period columns hidden
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP ALTER COLUMN _EMP_DH_DEBUT ADD HIDDEN;
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP ALTER COLUMN _EMP_DH_FIN ADD HIDDEN;
GO

--> verifying
SELECT * FROM dbo.T_EMPLOYE_EMP FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
ORDER BY EMP_ID, _EMP_DH_DEBUT;
GO
```